# Use same controller for multiple routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to write the following routes so you don't have to specify the same controller each time?...

```
get 'jobs' => 'pages#jobs'
get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'
get 'terms' => 'pages#terms'
get 'privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are couple of alternatives:

Out of the three, the first one i.e., `Using scope as "/"` would create the exact same routes as the ones created by the `routes defined in the question`.

### 1. Using scope as "/"

```
scope "/", controller: :pages do
  get 'jobs' 
  get 'contact' 
  get 'terms' 
  get 'privacy' 
end
```

**Creates routes as below:**

```
jobs    GET    /jobs(.:format)                      pages#jobs
contact GET    /contact(.:format)                   pages#contact
terms   GET    /terms(.:format)                     pages#terms
privacy GET    /privacy(.:format)                   pages#privacy
```

### **2. Using Scope as "pages"**

```
scope :pages, controller: :pages do
  get 'jobs' 
  get 'contact' 
  get 'terms' 
  get 'privacy' 
end
```

**Creates routes as below:**

```
jobs    GET    /pages/jobs(.:format)                pages#jobs
contact GET    /pages/contact(.:format)             pages#contact
terms   GET    /pages/terms(.:format)               pages#terms
privacy GET    /pages/privacy(.:format)             pages#privacy
```

### **3. Nesting routes**

```
resources :pages do
  member do
    get 'jobs' 
    get 'contact' 
    get 'terms' 
    get 'privacy' 
  end
end
```

**Creates routes as below:**

```
jobs_page    GET    /pages/:id/jobs(.:format)            pages#jobs
contact_page GET    /pages/:id/contact(.:format)         pages#contact
terms_page   GET    /pages/:id/terms(.:format)           pages#terms
privacy_page GET    /pages/:id/privacy(.:format)         pages#privacy
```

Comment: If the controller and the scope is the same, for #2, there is another way using namespace like this `namespace :pages do;get 'contact';end`, which will give routes like this `GET /pages/contact(.:format) pages#contact`