# Rails: same controller for multiple routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a ArticleController with route `resources :articles` and routes are like this

```
http://localhost:3000/articles
```

I need the same controller to handle all the CRUD actions below

```
http://localhost:3000/personal/articles
http://localhost:3000/stuff/articles
```

So all 3 above routes should be handled by Article controller for all article CRUD actions. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use same controller for multiple routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773935/use-same-controller-for-multiple-routes)

Comment: you need nested routes

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :articles
scope '/personal' do
  resources :articles
end
scope '/stuff' do
  resources :articles
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html